# sql query to reconstruct rows of a spreadsheet from a table of cells

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I extracted a set of unstructured spreadsheets from google docs and loaded them into a database with the following structure for further analysis.

[image]

My goal would be to go from the rows that look like this:

```
SpreadsheetTitle WorksheetTitle Row Column Value
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   3   1   September 2005
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   5   2   Rate 
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   5   3   # of Sales
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   5   4   Total Spent
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   6   1   Accuquote
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   6   2   $70
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   6   3   45
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   6   4   $3150
Copy of updated accounting backup (a-e) Accuquote   6   5   PAID
```

To this:

```
SpreadsheetTitle WorksheetTitle Row Column1 Column2 Column3.....etc...etc..
```

I can think of ways to proceed by writing non-sql code, but I'm curious to know if I can use something along the lines of a recursive query (maybe) or a pivot function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a pivot expert: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

But would something like this work:

```
SELECT  SpreadsheetTitle,
        WorksheetTitle,
        row,
        [1] AS Col1,
        [2] AS Col2
FROM    ( SELECT    'spreadsheet' SpreadsheetTitle, 'worksheet' WorksheetTitle, 0 Row, 1 AS [ColumnID], 1 VALUE 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    'spreadsheet' SpreadsheetTitle, 'worksheet' WorksheetTitle, 0 Row, 2 AS [ColumnID], 2 VALUE 
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    'spreadsheet2' SpreadsheetTitle, 'worksheet' WorksheetTitle, 0 Row, 1 AS [ColumnID], 3 VALUE 
        ) AS flat PIVOT
    ( MAX(Value) FOR [ColumnID] IN ( [1], [2] ) ) AS pivoted
```